# Trying to remove spaces from a string but getting an error saying 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I have tried to add some inputs together to form a file name, but they seem to have spaces in between, I have tried to get rid of the spaces using replace, and join. but it says join is not defined, and 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace'. please help
my code is:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

    def k100():
            tsave = Turtle()
            tsavescreen = tsave.getscreen()
            pictype = input("What type of photo would you like this to be saved as? (png, jpg, pdf, ...) ")
            name = input("What would you like to call your masterpiece? ")
            fnws = name,".",pictype #fnws means file_name_with_spaces
            join(fnws)
            fnns = fnws.replace(" ", "") #fnns means file_name_no_spaces
            tsavescreen.getcanvas().postscript(file=fnns, colormode='color')
            #open("C:\Users\GURNHH\OneDrive - Rugby School\ICT\Python").close()
            #open("pythontest11.pdf").close()
            print("It has been saved as: ", fnns)
            print("It has been saved as: ", fnns)
```

Answer (score 1):

As using the `,` creates a tuple, and what you need is a string, you should do the following:

Change:

```
fnws = name,".",pictype
```

To:

```
fnws = name, + "." + pictype
```

Now, `fnws` is a String variable so you can apply the replace on it.

Also, consider to use the strip method, with strip you can remove any characters you would like to, simply writing (default is removing whitespcace):

```
fnws = (name, + "." + pictype).strip()
```

> string.strip(s[, chars])
>
> Return a copy of the string with leading and trailing characters
>   removed. If chars is omitted or None, whitespace characters are
>   removed. If given and not None, chars must be a string; the characters
>   in the string will be stripped from the both ends of the string this
>   method is called on.

Answer (score 0):

if you variables have leading and/or trailing whitespace you can call strip function.  You use it like this

`fnws = "{}.{}".format(name.strip(),pictype.strip())`

For more information on strip function you can go here [strip doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip)

Comment: do you know why I can't open the file? I have tried using adobe, Microsoft edge, and word, but neither work. (btw I'm trying to save a turtle-drawn pic)